# Make wordpress load assets over https before installation

Tags: wordpress, security, https

I am trying to install wordpress on a server that sits behind a front facing HTTPS load balancer.

The problem is the server I am trying to install it on does not use HTTPS, as it is in a secure network and only talks to the load balancer.

I guess wordpress detects the servers protocol, so now when I try to install it wants to load all assets over HTTP.

The browser yells at me for this with the "mixed-content" warnings. Even trying to run through the install process is a difficult without the cs/js files loading.

All I want to do is tell wordpress to try and load these files over HTTPS, despite the server "seemingly" not supporting it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I found out how to do this.

You have to go through the install process without css/js files up until the page you put in your database information.

After you do this wordpress creates the "wp-config.php" file. In that file you have to add these 2 variables:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
```

This basically makes your server look like an HTTPS server to wordpress, and everything works for my load balancer network.